# Tree view poor usability

Tags: c#, java, winforms, treeview, usability

I am working on a huge software product (Java/C#) that manages and classifies the data in a tree view. The tree view can sometime become quite large and difficult to manage. 
I have looked around for better ways of presenting the data to users and replace the Tree view default presenter, I found the following:
http://ripul.blogspot.com/2005/10/tree-view-removal-surgery_112919819961257081.html
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/03/trees-treeviews-and-ui.html

The question is more for usability experts but since the software is written in Java/C# there might be other tree view replacements I don't know of.
Any ideas from the community?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it fits your model, consider replacing it with a grouped-list implementation.

I would suggest you to try this open-source project called [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) (Note: I didn't write it - I'm just a happy user).

It offers a flexible set of list implementations, as well as a tree-list implementation if you still need a multilevel hierarchy (see below).

You can bind anything enumerable to it and/or use data-binding.

If you have massive data to display you can use one of its virtualized implementations.

Give it a go.

[image]
[image]

Comment: +1 for the Open source suggestion! This control is an enhancement of the tree or a list, what I am looking for is a way to enhance the usability-navigation of the tree as it contains tons and tons of data, not just the appearance :)

Comment: What is the nature of the navigation? If you have a massive navigation hierarchy (e.g. Outlook), then a tree-like navigator is hard to avoid. You can try a few things: 1) Refine the look & feel to have less lines (e.g. Gmail). 2) You _can) expand the selected tree branch while collapsing all others, but AFAIK - this one gets mixed reviews from users. 3) You can add a path string (even clickabled links) that will show you where you are currently. .. actually - if you're familiar with VS's XAML editor, then you might follow their idea of showing a path and only the children of the current node.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The tree I have is big and is something like, as you mentioned, outlook. Well, I think a tree is the natural way of presenting the data as it is a hierarchy but there should be something better :) I will have a look at your suggestions and come back to you later, thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Aha! I just realized what I had in mind - check out the Windows Explorer top bar behavior (in Windows 7). That's the better version (than the XAML thingy) that I was thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this one and honestly did not see any better options
http://www.dotnetperls.com/treeview

Comment: So this is better than ObjectListView?